# Is it possible to retrain a saved Neural Network using `sklearn`

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, pre-trained-model

I'm working on a project that looks to classify tweets and am using `sklearn`'s [neural network model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html). Is it possible to retrain this using `sklearn` and if so please guide me in the right direction. Also, is it worth it to retrain a model or should I just adjust values when constructing a network.

Comment: Your questions are pretty vague. You can, of course, adapt the network on new information. Or perform transfer learning. What exactly are you trying to accomplish and why is the training you've done not satisfactory?

Comment: The accuracy percentage was fairly low ~50. I'm trying to accomplish a neural network that can analyze the text of a tweet to categorize it.

Comment: This seems to be a model or hyperparameter issue. Where does 'retraining' come in to play?

Comment: So it is not worth it to retrain. I am new to this and am still learning. I should spend time working on parameters and "perfecting" those?

Comment: I would definitely focus on the hyperparameters first. Perhaps look around on the internet to see if anyone has done a similiar project (they definately have) and what approach and parameters they used

Comment: Hi, @ItsCardiBBaby, if you think the below answer was appropriate, I kindly request you to accept it as a verified answer, since it helps other users who might look into this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You could very well do that using the `partial_fit` method that `MLPClasifier` offers. I have written a sample code for doing it. You could very well retrain your saved model if you get data in batches and training is a costy operation for you so can't afford to train on the entire dataset each and every time you get a new batch of data.

```
import pickle
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_classes=4, n_features=11,
                       n_informative=4, weights=[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25],
                       random_state=0)

x_batch1 = X[0:500]
y_batch1 = y[0:500]

x_batch2 = X[500:999]
y_batch2 = y[500:999]

clf = MLPClassifier()
clf.partial_fit(x_batch1, y_batch1, classes = np.unique(y))  # you need to pass the classes when you fit for the first time


pickle.dump(clf, open("MLP_classifier", 'wb'))
restored_clf = pickle.load(open("MLP_classifier", 'rb'))

restored_clf.partial_fit(x_batch2, y_batch2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following.

```py
from sklearn.externals import joblib
##Suppose your trained model is named MyTrainedModel
##This is how you save it in a file called MyTrainedModelFile.txt.
joblib.dump(MyTrainedModel, 'MyTrainedModelFile.txt')
##Later you can recall the model and use it
Loaded_model = joblib.load('MyTrainedModelFile.txt')
```

The tutorial is [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/).

Please let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: I am able to save a use the model. But the accuracy was fairly low. I was hoping that maybe I could retrain it to improve this number.

Comment: Really sorry! A little tired ... read retrain as retain... skipped the 'r' ... I thought you are asking about retaining the parameters and that's why the comment.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the help anyways!